# Usage of hReview with hidden elements

Tags: microformats

According to [Microformats](http://microformats.org/) we have very strict format for microformats. First of all there is a minor difference between [Microformats-hReview](http://microformats.org/wiki/hreview) and [Google-hReview](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146645).
How is this important?

Except for this, my problem is using Microformats in already written code, initially the code wasn't written in Microformat (hReview) style, so there is a lack of many attributes, this means that I can't use **hReview** with all attributes as is.

But despite of this, can I use **hReview** with hidden attributes like `class="rating"`, because I don't have it on the page, but I do want it to be indexed.

Can I mix tags of **hReview** with another tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion (as a long term follower of all this stuff), I'd mark it up using  the info at http://schema.org/Review instead. Just use meta elements for anything that isn't in the design but that you'd like to show.

Use the http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets tool to check what Google can see.

Comment: Why do you recommend Microdata over microformats? Is their really a benefit to using either?

Comment: I just get the feeling that all the momentum is towards microdata, while the newer itemprop (+ all others related) gives us a more official way to add metadata, rather than using classes (which have become much more associated with styling than metadata). The schema.org site sets out a lot of stuff, and I think that it's better documented and more "official" feeling that the microformats stuff ever was. I've completely switched to microdata on sites I develop, and don't do microformats anymore at all.

Comment: so instead of <span class="rating">5</span>, which I don't have on the page, I can use <meta name="rating" content="5" /> or rather <meta scheme="rating" content="5" />? Can I use meta tag with microformats?

Comment: Not sure if you can use meta with microformats. Try using one of the parsers to check.

Comment: @com, take a look at http://www.schema.org to see learn more about the Schema.org vocabulary; it's (arguably) the most important Microdata implementation out there now.  Or if you want to jump directly to reviews, go here:  http://schema.org/Review.